# Andengine - adding sprites avoiding collisions with existing

Tags: android, andengine, collision

I'm creating sprites and adding it to scene in loop in random places. I just want to check if newly created Sprite will cause collision with one of existing ones. Is there any simple way to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new sprite, add user data to it:

```
sprite.setUserData("sprite");
```

And then, after you created a positioned the sprite, before you add it iterate over the existing sprites:

```
int count = scene.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    IEntity entity = scene.getChild(i);
    if(entity instanceof Sprite) {
        if(entity.getUserData().equals("sprite"))
            if(((Sprite)entity).collidesWith(newSprite))
                //Don't add the new sprite.
}
```

The user data can be anything you want, it doesn't have to be a string.

Comment: thanks - I made loop like that, just working if there is some more efficient way than checking collisision against all other objects.